# losing property-address in delegate-call

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

Hi i'm using a UITableViewController which has a `@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString* name;` which is filled from the previous ViewController. And it has a UITextField with a `delegate=self` On viewWillAppear i set the text of the Field. All wonderfully working...

But in `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` i got a nil-pointer to self.name

Is there something i don't know much about threads so could this be the source of the problem?

EDIT:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
 self.title = textField.text;
 self.name = textField.text;  //Brakepoint self.name == nil
 [textField resignFirstResponder];
 return NO;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code for `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` where you are receiving the nil pointer? Are you setting self.name to nil at any point? For `NSString` you normally use `copy` not `retain`

Comment: at dealloc self.name is set to nil, and i need the reference not the copied object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called the TableViewController from two different NavigationControllers. One worked the other didn't. I got the bug only at one of them. The reference to name was from the other NavigationController....